# La propiedad se usa antes de su inicialización

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de fijar un día mínimo en un date-picker en Angular. Esto debo hacerlo asignándoselo a la propiedad **min** del **datePickerConfig**. Este valor *minDate* lo recibe en un input. Sin embargo, cuando intento igualar **min: minDate** me arroja el siguiente error: Property 'minDate' is used before its initialization.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl, FormGroup, NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import * as moment from "moment";

@Component({
  selector: "app-date-picker",
  templateUrl: "./date-picker.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./date-picker.component.scss"],
})
export class DatePickerFilterComponent implements OnInit {
  minimumDate: string;
  @Input() name: string = "default";
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;
  @Input() required: boolean = false;
  @Input() formGroupScope: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    default: new FormControl(),
  });
  @Input() enableSearchIcon = false;
  @Input() ngForm: NgForm;
  @Input() modePicker: string;
  @Input() minDate: string;
  @Output() modelChange = new EventEmitter();


  datePickerConfig = {
    firstDayOfWeek: "mo",
    monthFormat: "MMMM, YYYY",
    format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
    yearFormat: "YYYY",
    disableKeypress: false,
    closeOnSelect: true,
    enableMonthSelector: true,
    locale: "es",
    allowMultiSelect: false,
    weekDayFormat: "ddd",
    drops: "down",
    opens: "right",
    showGoToCurrent: true,
    multipleYearsNavigateBy: 10,
    showMultipleYearsNavigation: false,
    min: this.minDate
  };


  hasError(controlName) {
    const control = this.formGroupScope.get(controlName);
    return (
      !control.valid &&
      (control.touched || control.dirty || this.ngForm.submitted)
    );
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  changeEvent(event: any) {
    this.modelChange.emit(moment(event.date).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
  }
```

Acá les dejo mi código. Eh intentado todo, pero no logro encontrar una solución. Espero su respuesta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Input() minDate: string;` no recibe al momento de inicializar tu componente.  Este comportamiento es normal, pero un poco dificil de entender. Para solucionarlo debes esperar a que `minDate` reciba el valor. La manera más sencilla de hacer esto es convertirlo a accesores de propiedades dinamicas:

```js
private _minDate: Usuario
public get minDate(): Date {
  return this._minDate
}
@Input() public set minDate(value: Date) {
  this._minDate = value

  this.datePickerConfig.min = value 
}
```

Comment: Me sirvió esto! Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si es posible, @Legna podrías explicarme un poco como funciona eso? Gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo [esta lectura](https://medium.com/angular-chile/angular-componentes-y-sus-ciclos-de-vida-aa639e13a688) sobre el tema del ciclo de vida de los componentes y [esto otro](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) sobre accesores a propiedades dinámicas. (Tambien `set` se menciona aqui)

Comment: Muchas gracias!